# jhipster: How to make a gateway call a microservice using HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, microservices

When configuring the `server.ssl` properties in the `application-prod.yml` of a microservice, the gateway is no more able to call the microservice (`org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException`).

This is the gateway configuration:

```
Application 'discovery' is running! 
Access URLs:  
Local:          https://localhost:52568
External:       https://172.24.36.10:52568
Profile(s):     [prod]
```

How can the gateway call an https microservice?

The StackTrace of the error is:

> Stack trace:Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 172.24.36.5:52568 failed to respond at
>   rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:58) at
>   rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:465) at
>   rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342) at
>   com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102) ...
>   182 common frames omitted

Comment: In the JHipster Registry (Eureka), do you see the services registered?  You should be able to see their IP as well, is it using https?

Comment: The service is registered. But the gateway tries to call it using http.